# Search specific permutation of permutationsubset with constraints

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, permutation, inverse-transform

Iam searching `one` permutation `P` consisting of `p1...pn` of following subset `S`.
`S` is defined of the Labels `L`.
`L1...Lk`. Where a `L` contains `pi...pj`.
Where the inverse of `P` has at most `k-1` decreasing adjecent Elements. `k <= n`.

Example:

`n := 4`

`k := 2`

`L1 := 1,2`

`L2 := 3,4`

`L := L1,L2,L1,L2`

`S := 1324,1423,2314,2413`

one solution would be `P := 1342`

no solution would be `P := 3142` because decreasing adjecent elements are `2` but only max`1` ist allowed because `k =2`.

Exists therefor an algorithm to find `P` of `S` defined by `L`?

Currently I use bruteforce to figure one  permutation `P`, but its getting very fast unusable slow.

Comment: Am I correct that you just need a random permutation of `p1..pn` meeting the condition? And then will figure out `L` from that?

Comment: Also do you need all allowed permutations to show up with equal probability, or is some chance of getting each sufficient?

Comment: I just need one permutation ```P``` of ```S``` defined by ```L```. ```L,S,n,k``` is given and ```P``` is searched.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "defined by L". But I have a `O(kn^3)` memory and `O(kn^4)` time algorithm for finding a random permutation of `1..n` with at most `k-1` decreasing adjacent elements.

Comment: If `n < 100` this might be good enough?

Comment: ```L``` defined in which Index of ```P``` which ```pi``` is allowed Example ```L=L1,L2```, ```L1=1,2,3```,```L2=4,5,6```. So ```S``` can be ```123456,321654,321456``` but not ```456123, 412356,162345```.  ```n < 100``` better then bruteforce

Comment: In the example above ```L1``` covers the indices ```0,1,2``` of the permutation and ```L2``` the indices ```3,4,5```

Comment: I am confused then. In the example in the description you give `n`, `k`, `L1`, L2`, `L`, and `S`. Then you talk about a solution and a non-solution that are not in `S` at all! I see how to define `S` from `L`, And `L` from a permutation. Is it therefore enough to find the permutation?

Comment: Iam searching ```P``` from ```S``` where the inverse of ```P``` has at most ```k-1``` decreasing adjecent elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73874122/585411 should be a viable strategy, though it is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

So each of `L1, ..., Lk` is a consecutive set of elements.  At each place we see `Li, Lj` in the definition of `L`, one of three things is true:

1. `i < j` in which case it is ascending.
2. `i = j` in which case it could be ascending or descending.
3. `i > j` in which case it must be descending.

By counting the number of places where case 3 is true, we get a minimum number of descending elements already in the definition of `L`.

Next, for each `Li` we have a pattern we can write down with `len(Li)-1` `;` and `,` where a `;` means that there are elements of other `Lj`s between two members of `Li`, and `,` means that `Li` elements are adjacent and so the order of the elements may result in a descent. We want to know, "For each possible number of descents within `Li`, how many permutations of `Li` have that number of descents?"

We will think of building the permutations as follows:

```
The first element goes at position 0.
The second element goes to position 0 or 1. (If at 0, the first element is moved.)
The third element goes to position 0, 1, or 2.
etc
```

A descent is when the next element is smaller than the previous, at a transition matching a `,`.

We actually will want the following data structure for later use:

```
cache[Li] gives:
    by how many elements are chosen:
        by the last element chosen:
            by the number of descents we will add:
                how many ways of finishing this permutation
```

So we can write a recursive function that takes:

1. The pattern for `Li`.
2. How many elements have been chosen.
3. What index was last chosen.

It then returns a dictionary mapping descents to count of ways to finish the permutation for `Li`.

Memoize that and we get our desired data structure.

Now we'll repeat the idea.  We want:

```
cache2[i] gives:
    by number of descents to use:
        how many permutations of L[i], L[i+1], ..., L[k] meet it.
```

Again we can write a recursive function using `cache` to calculate this, and we can memoize it to get `cache2`.

---

And NOW we can reverse the process.

1. We know how many descents came from the definition of `L`.
2. We know the distribution of remaining descents from `cache2[1]`, so we can randomly pick how many descents there will be meeting our condition among `L1...Lk`.
3. For `L1...Lk` we can look at `cache[L1][1][0]` and `cache2[i+1]` to figure out how many descents there will be within `Li` with the correct probability.
4. For each `Li` we can look at how many descents we want to wind up with, its pattern, and `cache2[Li]` to figure out a random sequence of inserts winding up with the right pattern. The first insert is always at `0`. After that you always know the size, and where the last insert was, and how many descents are left.  So for each possiblenext insert you figure out if it counts as a descent (look at both pattern, and whether it is before the last insert), and the number of ways to finish from there. Then you can choose the next insert randomly with the right possibility.
5. For each `Li` we can turn the pattern of inserts into the list of values in order. (I will explain this step more.)
6. We can now follow the pattern of `L` and fill in all of the values.

Now for step 5, let's illustrate with your example from the chat.  Suppose that `L2 = [4, 5, 6]` and the pattern of inserts we came up with was `[0, 1, 0]`.  How do we figure out the arrangement of values?

Well first we do our inserts:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
```

This says that the first element (`4`) goes to the third place, the second (`5`) to the first, and the third (`6`) to the second.  So our permutation for `L2` is `[5, 6, 4]`.

---

This will be a lot of code to write. But it will be polynomial.  Specifically if `m` is the count of the most common label, `cache` will have total size at most `O(k m^2)`. Thanks to memoization, each entry takes `O(m)` to calculate. Everything else is small relative to that.  So total space is `O(k m^2)` and time is `O(k m^3)`.